# Setoolkit error

Tags: python

after starting setoolkit one message appears as :

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 257, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/set/src/core/setcore.py", line 844, in pull_version
    version = urlopen(url).read().rstrip().decode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 210, in open
    return self.open_unknown(fullurl, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 222, in open_unknown
    raise IOError, ('url error', 'unknown url type', type)
IOError: [Errno url error] unknown url type: 'https'
 Select from the menu:

   1) Social-Engineering Attacks
   2) Penetration Testing (Fast-Track)
   3) Third Party Modules
   4) Update the Social-Engineer Toolkit
   5) Update SET configuration
   6) Help, Credits, and About

  99) Exit the Social-Engineer Toolkit
```

can somebody help?